# How to convert method to proc for &method usage in Ruby

Tags: ruby, proc

For learning purposes, I'm exploring if I can convert these three method calls:

```
Foo::Bar.logger.debug(a)
Foo::Bar.logger.debug(b)
Foo::Bar.logger.debug(c)
```

into a single-line statement using the shorthand proc `&method` approach:

```
[a, b, c].each(&method(:'Foo::Bar.logger.debug'))
```

`.debug` does not respond to `.to_proc` so naturally:

```
NameError: undefined method `Foo::Bar.logger.debug' for class `#<Class:Foo>'
```

This does work; however, but isn't as succinct as the former:

```
logger = Proc.new { |x| Foo::Bar.logger.debug(x) }                                                                                                           
[a, b, c].each(&logger)
```

Is it possible for the former approach to work?

Comment: Did you read the error message? What is the name of the method the error message tells you it cannot find? What does that tell you about the argument that `method` expects from you? What does the error message tell you about *where* it is trying to find that method? What does that tell you about how `method` works? Where does it say anything about not responding to `to_proc`? Why do you come to the conclusion that the problem is with `to_proc`?

Comment: I guess `[a, b, c].each { |x| Foo::Bar.logger.debug(x) }` would be too simple? ;-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I did read the error message but I didn't understand it. I got the idea that passing `&method` to a func that accepts a block calls `.to_proc` on the method from a StackOverflow linked blog: https://www.skorks.com/2013/04/ruby-ampersand-parameter-demystified/ (section: The Symbol To Proc Trick). It didn't occur to me that the `method` method needed to be called on the method's class specifically.

Comment: @Stefan Definitely simple, but as mentioned above, this was an exercise in learning more about procs and the `&method` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the `method` method incorrectly. From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method):

> **method(sym) → method**
>   Looks up the named method as a receiver in *obj*, returning a `Method` object (or raising `NameError`).

You'd usually say

```
m = some_obj.method(:some_method_name)
```

and then work with `m`. Saying:

```
method(:Foo::Bar.logger.debug)
```

should be giving you a `TypeError` because because `:Foo` is a symbol, not a class or module and trying to apply `::` to a symbol makes no sense. I suspect that you're actually saying:

```
method(':Foo::Bar.logger.debug')
```

as that will produce the error you're seeing. Assuming that that's the case, then you're actually trying to get a reference to the method named `':Foo::Bar.logger.debug'` in the object `self`.

If you want a reference to the `debug` method in `Foo::Bar.logger` then you'd say:

```
Foo::Bar.logger.method(:debug)
```

Combining that your `to_proc` call (via `&`):

```
[a, b, c].each(&Foo::Bar.logger.method(:debug))
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation.

Comment: @doremi You're welcome, learning is why we're here, we're not here to brag about how much we think we know by putting other people down.